# Load webfont only if font not available locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts

I saw Remy Sharp's solution on how to detect whether a font exists, but it's a really old implementation. https://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript

Is there a better way to do this now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that you mentioned holds still valid, but prioritizing a local font over a web source does not even require the use of Javascript coding. You can do it with src specification order in CSS font-face. The order of source you mention in there is maintained in attempting in priority of lookup for the font. So if you put local sources first, they will be used if present instead of downloading from web URL. For more detail information and reference, you can see the following:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization?hl=en#defining-font-family-with-font-face

Hope that helped.